# How do I destroy the Harley Heads?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

I'm talking about the Harley Heads in the Steel Mill where if you press the button, you hear Harley talking through the intercom. I know I have to do *something* to them, because there's a count for them in the Riddler's challenges under the Steel Mill, just like the Joker Balloons and TYGER cameras.

I've tried:

- pushing the button several times, but it just seems to annoy her
- using the explosive gel, but doing so makes him use it on the wall behind the head, which does nothing
- trying to use the various Batarangs at my disposal, but there's no targeting reticule for them

What do I need to do to destroy these?

Comment: I call them Quintercoms.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Shoot a Remote Electrical Charge directly at her head. It should pop off and count it as completed.

Comment: Thanks! I actually figured it out in the midst of posting this, but I figured I'd ask anyway in case others were confused. :)

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes The bad part is, I don't recall the game telling me to do this. Someone must have figured it out because I actually came across it while watching a video, and had no idea I had to destroy them.

Comment: Batman destroys the first one in a cut scene after rescuing the doctor in the steel mill.